# DreamFactory and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rest

Can you use DreamFactory with MS SQL Server (non-azure) install on my local server?  I am trying to find rest service that will work with my AngularJS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, DreamFactory DSP supports MS SQL Server (azure or local install). DSP installs are not currently supported on Windows OS, but you can connect to your local install of your database as a remote SQL DB service from any DSP using the same setup as noted [here](http://blog.dreamfactory.com/add-a-rest-api-to-any-sql-db-in-minutes). DSPs come with several sample apps, one of which is AngularJS based. If you have more questions about db connections or using Angular, please see http://dreamfactory.com/developers/support.